# Printing a file to a process stdout, using dd (Android)

Tags: android, shell, stdout, dd

I am trying to get the output of dd the following way.
The idea is to programmatically capture whatever dd sends to "of".

```
//Process p;
// ...
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "dd if=/dev/something of=stdout bs=1024"});
```

Using "cat /some_file" instead of "dd ..." command **works** as expected but I wanted this to work with dd.

What should I use for stdout, as /dev/stdout does not exist in Android?

Will this even work?

You can assume the app has root privileges.

Comment: I think you get it to `stdout` if you skip the `of` parameter. http://ss64.com/bash/dd.html

Comment: Hmm i think that might just work. But i also need it not to print its status messages at the end. Docs mention `status=noxfer' but Android's dd does not have the 'status' option.

Comment: status message is printed to `STDERR` for me. At least appending "2>/dev/null" on the console get's rid of the message.

Comment: Doing "dd if=/dev/something bs=1024 2>/dev/null" answers my question. If you place an answer with it I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device is not too big you could dd it to a file and then cat the file to stout ...

```
//Process p; 
// ... 
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "dd if=/dev/something of=/dev/mnt/sdcard/myfile bs=1024"}); 
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cat", "/dev/mnt/sdcard/myfile"});
```

good luck

--EDITED--

I've just remembered that if you omit the "of=" operand the "dd" command will write to the stdout.
So your code change to:

```
//Process p;  
// ...  
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "dd if=/dev/something bs=1024"});
```

I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Sorry, the file is big, i do not want it to cat to a file.